# Updating Views in hsqldb 2.2.9

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have a view **v** on a table **x**. A background task creates a new table **y** to which the view **v** should now point to. To do so, I use the following command

`ALTER VIEW PUBLIC.v AS
    SELECT id, name, price FROM y`

After that I confirmed that view **v** points to the table **y**, so far so good. But if i now try to drop the old table **x** I get the following error message

```
Error code -5502, SQL state 42502: dependent objects exist: PUBLIC.V in statement [drop table x]
```

So if check the system view table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` with the following command

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='PUBLIC' AND TABLE_NAME='V'
```

It gives me the the following view definition:

```
SELECT T.id,T.name,T.price FROM PUBLIC.x
```

Which says the view points to the old table **x**. I there a way to update the definition? Dropping and than recreating the view is sadly not an option for me, because i have other views depending on this view and i don't wan't to recreate them with every update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. It will be fixed in the next update (version 2.3.2).

One alternative is to close the database then reopening it